# @property pointing to a singleton (or sharedInstance) : strong or weak and why?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, memory-management, properties, singleton

Let's say I have a `sharedInstance` initialized like this

```
+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance
{
    static TheConstantsPlaceholder *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[TheConstantsPlaceholder alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

then, what should I do (and why should I do like this) in a class referencing to this object:

- `@property (strong, readwrite) MySingleton * mySingleton` ?
- OR :  `@property (weak, readwrite) MySingleton * mySingleton` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`weak` is only useful if the object being referenced can be deallocated, in the case of your `sharedInstance` this will not happen - the object is created once and then lives for the duration of application. So stick with `strong` here (you could also use `assign` as you know it is safe to do so, but there is no strong reason to do so and it might be confusing).

Comment: Why might it be confusing?

Comment: Because there is no reason to use it and it entertains the possibility that the shared instance may be deallocated.